# Upload large chunked google drive files error

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Im trying to upload large files to google drive. To preserve memory I am adding the file in chunks using Google's media file upload .

The file uploads fine however I get a warning from PHP `( Warning: rawurldecode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given )`

I have posted my code below incase I have any mistakes :

```
$file3 = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();

  $file3->setName($zipName3 . '.zip');
  $file3->setDescription('Testing document ZIP backups');
  $file3->setMimeType('application/zip');
  $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
  $client->setDefer(true);
  $request = $service->files->create($file3);

  $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload($client, $request, 'application/zip', null,true,$chunkSizeBytes);
  $media->setFileSize(filesize($zipPath3));

  $result = $service->files->create($file3, array('mediaUpload' => $media));
  $status = false;
  $handle = fopen($zipPath3, "rb");
  while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
     $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
     $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
  }
  $result = false;
  if($status != false) {
  $result = $status;
  }
  fclose($handle);

  print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem to have fixed the problem :

```
$file3 = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();

  $file3->setName($zipName3 . '.zip');
  $file3->setDescription('Testing document ZIP backups');
  $file3->setMimeType('application/zip');
  $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
  $client->setDefer(true);
  $request = $service->files->create($file3);

  $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload($client, $request, 'application/zip', null,true,$chunkSizeBytes);
  $media->setFileSize(filesize($zipPath3));

  **$result = $service->files->create($file3, array('mediaUpload' => $media));**
  $status = false;
  $handle = fopen($zipPath3, "rb");
  while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
     $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
     $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
  }
  $result = false;
  if($status != false) {
  $result = $status;
  }
  fclose($handle);

  print_r($result);
```

The culprit:

```
$result = $service->files->create($file3, array('mediaUpload' => $media));
```

Dont know why I was passing the $media object with the file creation but removing that solved the issue :

```
$result = $service->files->create($file3);
```